# How to perform shift click in Selenium 3.6 with IE11

Tags: java, selenium

```
public void shiftClick() {
    if(WebBrowser.isInternetExplorer()) { 
        try {
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            try {
                WindowManagement.setBrowserFocus();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
            this.clickElement();
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            throw new AssertionError(e.getMessage());
        }

    } else { 
        Actions actions = new Actions(Browser.getWebDriver(null));
        actions.keyUp(Keys.SHIFT).click(this.getWebElement()).keyUp(Keys.SHIFT).perform();
    }
}
```

The shift click does not work after I upgrade selenium from 2.53 to 3.6.0. I have tried AWT robot method and also tried Action key method. Is there any other way to perform shift click?

Comment: Is there any specific error that you are getting in console?

Comment: There is no error in console, so i'm confused

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific than "doesn't work". Debug your method with both 2.53 and 3.6.0 - does it take the same code path?

Comment: While debugging is it going inside if(WebBrowser.isInternetExplorer()) statement?

Comment: maybe robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT) and keyRelease method does not work, the element can be selected by click

Comment: Finaly, it can work after I upgrade IEDriverServer to 3.6.0.

Answer (score 0):

Tips for using WebDriver with IE (some ot them you can find [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver)):

- Disable `Enhanced Protected Mode` in IE options
- set browser zoom level to 100%
- For Windows 10, you also need to set "Change the size of text, apps, and other items" to 100% in display settings.
- For IE 11 only, you will need to set a registry entry - create a DWORD value named iexplore.exe with the value of 0:

  - For 32-bit Windows: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE`
  - For 64-bit Windows: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE`
- set the Protected Mode settings for each zone to be the same value
- use `requireWindowFocus` option
- try to enable `enableNativeEvents`, it sometimes helps
- always maximize IE window
- scroll to element before clicking on it in order to make the element visible within the screen, if the element is outside of IE window the click
  usually doesn't work

---

Working example for IE11 Windows 10 WebDriver 3.6.0.
and for this page: [w3schoold click whith SHIFT key pressed](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_dom_event_shiftkey) 
which shows how to detect whether SHIFT key is pressed when an element is clicked.

```
WebDriver driver= null;
try{
    InternetExplorerOptions opt =  new InternetExplorerOptions();
    // opt.enableNativeEvents();
    opt.requireWindowFocus();

    driver=new InternetExplorerDriver(opt);

    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    driver.get("https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_dom_event_shiftkey");

    final By clickOnThis = By.xpath("//p[ text() = 'Click on this paragraph. An alert box will tell you if you pressed the shift key or not.'  ]");
    final By message = By.xpath("//p[ text() = 'The shift key was pressed!' ]");

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait( driver, 5 );

    driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); 
    driver.switchTo().frame("iframeResult");

    WebElement clickOnMe = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(clickOnThis));

    Actions actions = new Actions( driver );

    actions.keyDown(Keys.SHIFT).click(clickOnMe).keyUp(Keys.SHIFT);
    actions.build().perform();

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(message));

    System.out.println("SHIFT-cLick detected");

    Thread.sleep(5000);
}finally {
    if(driver!=null) {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```